# Ruby on Rails : How to insert record with fetching value from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There are 3 tables : Student, College and Opted_College

I have a page say, Select College page(Add Opted Colleges page).

A Student will log into the application , and opt for different colleges. This college list is fetched from "College" table.
Once the college is selected , the details like : ( college_id + student_id )should be added in the Opted_College table.
For instatnce the Opted_College value might look like :

id College_id student_id
1     2            4

2 - R V College (college name)
4 - TestStudent (Student name)

I have not added a field for Student ID in the Select College page. 
I need to capture the student ID from the session and this data needs to be added to Opted_College table.

But after the Select College page is successfully submited, "NULL" value is entered  for Student_ID column in the Opted_College table.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In the create method of your OptedColleges controller you want something like this:

```
@optedcollege.student_id = current_user.id
@optedcollege.save
```

I am of course assuming you are using an authentication solution that provides a current_user helper method...